# Masstransit and ActiveMQ interop with Java

Tags: activemq-classic, masstransit

I'm creating a simple .NET 6.0 app that listens for messages from ActiveMQ, then publishes another message back to ActiveMQ. The original message is sent from Java in a JSON format and I see it consumed by the .NET Consumer. The published response is received by the Java app, but appears to be (sort of) Base64 encoded.

Is there a way to force plain JSON for the published messages? `cfg.UseJsonSerializer();` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What protocol is each client using?

Answer (score 0):

`cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer()` is likely your answer.

Set the `ContentType` to `application/json` and you should be fine.

However, MassTransit can consume both `ITextMessage` and `IBytesMessage`, but only produces `IBytesMessage` on output. So the Java application would need to know how to decode the byte message into UTF-8 and use the resulting JSON.